# Linux piping data containing backticks

Tags: linux, awk, sed, ash

I'm piping output from one command into a second:

```
mpc listall | mpc add
```

mpc listall returns the following data (can output 1 or more lines):

```
Dare - 16 - I´ll Be Your King.mp3
```

When piping it into the next command, it seems that my shell (Ash on BusyBox) converts the ´ into an asterisk, as I get the error

```
error adding Dare - 16 - I*ll Be Your King.mp3: No such directory
```

Manually adding double quotes works! like this:

```
mpc add "Dare - 16 - I´ll Be Your King.mp3"
```

So, I tried adding those by sed and awk, but in those cases the backtick gets converted to an asterisk again:

```
mpc listall | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/'
```

returns:

```
"Dare - 16 - I*ll Be Your King.mp3"
```

**So, question is, is there a way to pass backticks, or actually any character, as is, into another command without conversions?**

*By the way, obviously, it's quite bad to have this character in the file name in the first place, but I want my code to be robust and able to handle anything thrown at it.*

Comment: Note that `´` is actually [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent), **not** backtick, also known as the [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent). If it actually was a backtick in your filename, double quotes wouldn't prevent it to expand as a command substitution.

Comment: To handle your acute accent (but also the backtick), you should quote the filename with a single quote - try with `sed "s/^/'/;s/\$/'/"`.

Comment: @randomir, yes this works, but not when you pipe it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct solution the problem, but a work-around (that's actually better, because it uses the API) in python using the python-mpd2 library:

```
myMpdClient = MPDClient() 
myMpdClient.connect("localhost", 6600)  # connect to localhost:6600
myMpdClient.findadd('base','directory-name')
myMpdClient.close()
```

I'll accept a working solution to the actual proposed problem, instead of this one, if someone posts a working solution.